# How to fill each tab of the tab control's itemslist with one user control dynamically from the mainviewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tabcontrol

My **MainView** contains a TabControl with an ItemTemplate and a ContentTemplate.
The TabControl's ItemsSource is bound to the Property `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> TabCollection` in my **MainViewModel**.

**TabViewModel**:

```
    namespace LuxUs.ViewModels
{
    public class TabViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object VM {get; set;}      
        
        public TabViewModel(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public TabViewModel(string name, object vm)
        {
            Name = name;
            VM = vm;          
        }        
    }
}
```

I want to create the tabs with their tab's header AND content dynamically from the MainViewModel like this...:

**MainViewModel**:

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LuxUs.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
    {
        
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> TabCollection { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            TabCollection = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();
            TabCollection.Add(new TabViewModel("Dachdefinition", new DachdefinitionViewModel()));
            TabCollection.Add(new TabViewModel("Baukörperdefinition"));
            TabCollection.Add(new TabViewModel("Fassade"));
            TabCollection.Add(new TabViewModel("Raumdefinition"));
            TabCollection.Add(new TabViewModel("Treppenloch | Galerieöffnung"));
            
        }       
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<UserControl  x:Class="LuxUs.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LuxUs.Views"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:LuxUs.Models"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LuxUs.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}" >
              
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UserControl>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding VM}" />
                        </UserControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

... but the content of each tab won't show. Instead, I get this text. The ViewModel ist the correct one but it should load the view instead of showing this text, of course:

[image: Screenshot of the View]

The first tab's ViewModel **DachdefinitionViewModel** has only an empty constructor:

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LuxUs.ViewModels
{
    public sealed class DachdefinitionViewModel : ObservableObject
    {       
        public DachdefinitionViewModel()
        {
  
        }  
    }
}
```

And here is its view **Dachdefinition.xaml**:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="LuxUs.Views.Dachdefinition"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LuxUs.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LuxUs.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:DachdefinitionViewModel></vm:DachdefinitionViewModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="50">
...
...
...
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is the binding correct here or do I need to bind differently? Why is the view not showing up inside the first tab?

Comment: As you can see the content refers to the correct ViewModel but somehow the view won't show. Do I need to add something in the MainView.xaml to make it work or is the problem the binding of `Dachdefinition.xaml` and `DachdefinitionViewModel.cs?` First, I would like to know if the xaml and viewmodel logic is correct. If so, it must be the binding as mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to connect view model with correct view via DataTemplate.

DataTemplate provides visual representation for data type which doesn't have it (your view model). If you don't specify DataTemplate, you will get default one: TextBlock with string representation of object (result of ToString() method, default to type name).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DachdefinitionViewModel}">
              <views:Dachdefinition />
         </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}" >
      
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding VM}" />
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign the DataTemplate DYNAMICALLY in the viewmodel? Here I need to explicitly say which viewmodel it is but could I do this in the constructor of the viewmodel, too?

Comment: @timunix That happens automatically when you have multiple DataTemplate resources which have their DataType property set appropriately.

Comment: Okay but is this good practice in general or just to help me quickly? I feel like it's a bit hard-coded.

Comment: @timunix, it is common practice, and actually encouraged. write it once, and ALL objects of that type will be displayed properly. DataTempates are even treated by framework as special type of resources: DataType serves as resource key.

Comment: do check my answer. let me know if you are having trouble understanding the solution

Answer (score 2):

Your TabControl declaration should look like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DachdefinitionViewModel}">
            <local:Dachdefinition/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding VM}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

And the `Dachdefinition` UserControl must not set its own DataContext property, because the DataContext value is supposed to be inherit from the control's parent element, i.e. the TabItem.

```
<UserControl x:Class="LuxUs.Views.Dachdefinition" ...>
   <!--
       do not set UserControl.DataContext here
   -->
   <Grid Margin="50">
       ...
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Indeed, I removed the DataContext and it is still working.

Comment: Your XAML will not work as expected unless you remove the DataContext assignment from the UserControl. Explicitly setting the DataContext is a programming error. You will realized that as soon as you have real data in a DachdefinitionViewModel.

Comment: I already removed it Clemens, thank you! Now I can finally care about the Models and their mapping to an SQLite-Database.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is a problem in databinding.**
at
`<ContentControl Content="{Binding VM}" />`

> This line would just display ToString() value of the object bound to
> it. (VM in this case).
>
> Instead you can try using ContentTemplateSelection where you can choose the type of ContentTemplate in run time based on the type of object bound to it.

```
class TabContentTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DachdeTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is TabViewModel tabViewModel)
        {
            if (tabViewModel.VM != null && tabViewModel.VM is DachdefinitionViewModel)
            {
                return DachdeTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return DefaultTemplate;
            }
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}


   <DataTemplate x:Key="DachdeTemplate">
      
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeOtherTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>


    <local:TabContentTemplateSelector x:Key="myTabContentTemplateSelector"
                                      DachdeTemplate="{StaticResource DachdeTemplate}"
                                      DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource 
                                      SomeOtherTemplate}"
                                      />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid> 
        <TabControl  ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}" 
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource 
                    myTabContentTemplateSelector}" > 
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate> 
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/41e70f/dynamically-selecting-datatemplate-for-wpf-listview-way-1/
Check this for how to dynamically change template.. In the template you can use any kind of user control.